# using a dialog box to select a file and working on it

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

i have a code that will compare headers between two worksheets in different workbooks and copy paste data in the main workbook.

```
   'lastCol = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   lastCol = 15
   lastrow = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Set cmpRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, lastCol))
   a = cmpRng
   i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open("Z:\RMG\RMG Data Master\Global_HEADCOUNT.xls")
   Worksheets("GLOBAL_HEADCOUNT").Select
   Mastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Set mastRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Mastcol))
   b = mastRng

For k = 1 To lastCol
    For n = 1 To Mastcol
        If UCase(a(3, k)) = UCase(b(1, n)) Then
        Windows("Global_HEADCOUNT").Activate
            Worksheets("GLOBAL_HEADCOUNT").Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(j, n)).Copy
            Windows("Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
            Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
            Cells(i + 1, k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
Call Wbk.Close(False)
```

**Now the problem** in this is that every time the file name changes the user has to go in the code and change it, which may lead to problems, so i want to avoid that providing them an alternative to select the files using a dialog box

**what i know:**

i have a little knowledge of how to achieve this,

```
'The folder containing the files to be recap'd
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.InitialFileName = "G:\Work\" '<----- Change this to where the files are stored.
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
'allow multiple file selection
fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
fd.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
filechosen = fd.Show
'Create a workbook for the recap report
Set Master = ThisWorkbook
If filechosen = -1 Then
```

but i use the above code for something else and i am having difficulty integrating my code with it... all i am asking is for a little guidance to do it as the result i am trying to achieve is a little different :) ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I generally use to force a user to select the workbook that needs to be opened:

```
Dim f As Object, fso As Object, flder As Object
Dim myfile As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
        End
    End If
    myfile = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Set Wbk= Workbooks.Open(myfile)
```

Alternatively you can store all the file locations in cells on the first sheet, that way they only need to update the spreadsheet with the new file location and not edit the code or select the workbook every time.

To integrate this with your code, it would look something like this:

```
'lastCol = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = 15
lastrow = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set cmpRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(3, lastCol))
a = cmpRng
i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim f As Object, fso As Object, flder As Object
Dim myfile As String
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' this variable lets us go back to our original workbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet ' this variable lets us go back to our original sheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cancel Selected"
        End
    End If
    myfile = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
dim wbk as workbook ' use this variable to reference the workbook we're opening
dim ghws as worksheet ' this variable should reference the new sheet that gets opened
Set Wbk= Workbooks.Open(myfile)   
set ghws = activesheet

ghws.Select
Mastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set mastRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Mastcol))
b = mastRng

For k = 1 To lastCol
    For n = 1 To Mastcol
        If UCase(a(3, k)) = UCase(b(1, n)) Then
        wbk.Activate
            ghws.Range(Cells(2, n), Cells(j, n)).Copy
            wbk.Activate
            Ws.Select
            Cells(i + 1, k).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
Call Wbk.Close(False)
```

Comment: hi paul this is what i am looking for....
as you see in my example i need to keep referencing the data from my other workbook.... can u guide me on how to reference them if its not a problem

Comment: i got that but thanks for confirming it :)
what about for loop headcount is the file i wish to be opened and dashboard is the master file
those lines have got me stumped

Comment: Ah sorry, I understand now, use wbk.activate to activate headcount, wb.activate to go back to your original one.

Comment: Edited my answer to give a better guide to how to integrate it, hope this helps you.

Comment: yea that helps but i see you have used the sheet name global headcount to copy i want to avoid that.... can it be changed to sheet one or something?

Comment: Sorry, missed that one, updated it just as I saw your comment.

Comment: i get a duplicate declaration error on wbk As Workbook obviously as there are two statements like this is this necessary
after the end with line